# How to read vector datasets using GDAL library

Tags: shapefile, gdal, vector, ogr, c++

Up to now, I have used GDAL in order to read raster information and geotiffs and show them with the help of OpenGL. Now I have a vector dataset, and by that, I mean I have the files with types:

**DBF File , PRJ File , SBN File , SBX File , SHP File , LOCK File , XML Document , SHX File**

I want to read the vector information **(e.g vertexes of the geometries and geometrical and topological relationships between feature)** and then show them using OpenGL.

- What part of GDAL library should I study?
- Can you introduce me a tutorial link that has fully covered what I
  want to read from the vector dataset?

Comment: well @Kurt what do you mean? the link that you have provided is this page's link! what do you mean by duplication? where is the question that mine has is duplicated with?

Comment: He probably meant the question you asked just after this one...

Comment: but @BradHars they aren't the same. This one is about `How to read vector datasets` but that one is about `How to show this information`

Comment: sepideh, you use the phrase to *"and then show them using opengl"* here, so it is hard to determine what the difference between this Q and your [next one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70801/please-introduce-me-a-free-3rd-party-library-appropriate-for-showing-geospatial) is. (Technical point: GDAL is for reading/writing rasters, and OGR for vectors. Though often bundled together they aren't the same.) We need you to back up and provide more context to your questions, give us the view from 10,000 feet as it were. What would be your end goal, after you have the answers?

Comment: the OGR C & C++ tutorial is here: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html

Comment: @BradHards, yes this was my intention. thank for correction